# Input Hash Size of ECDSA Signature over Curve secp521r1

Tags: hash, signature

For encryption authentication, I am using ECDSA signatures over the curve secp521r1. There is a hash function parameter, and as the curve is 521-bit, the hash output length should be > 512 bits, which is the highest offered output of the Standard SHA-2 hashes available.

However, in the SHA-3 specification, the cSHAKE function allows for variable length outputs, so is it recommended to use cSHAKE with an output length of something like 521 < n < 1024. If so, what is the recommended hash length to use?

Comment: It's a good question—and I don't know offhand what NIST's recommendations are for ECDSA over P-521, or whether there was _any_ approved hash function for it prior to SHA-3—but why do you want to do this?  There's no meaningful security advantage over, say, secp256k1, which naturally has a substantial performance advantage and also has high-quality implementations (particularly libsecp256k1) readily available.  And, if you're not restricted to NIST approval or FIPS rubber-stamping, you should use Ed25519 (or Ed448 if you really want a hedge against a modest cryptanalytic advance at any cost).

Comment: For comparison, Ed448, which works over a group of 446-bit order, is defined to use SHAKE256-912—in general, EdDSA chooses the hash to be twice the size of the order, to confidently avoid any modulo bias.  (This strategy [paid off](https://blog.cr.yp.to/20191024-eddsa.html) in another part of EdDSA _vs._ ECDSA.)  Certainly it wouldn't be _wrong_ to choose SHAKE256-1024 for use with secp521r1, under the somewhat questionable premise of using secp521r1 in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hash output length does not *need* to be larger than 512 bits; the ECDSA specification can handle any length. The curve secp521r1 is usually considered to provide 256 bits of security (even though it provides a bit more), see Table 2 of [NIST SP 800-57](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-57pt1r4.pdf) for example. Therefore, a 512-bit hash, i.e. SHA-512, should be fine ("The security strength of the hash function used shall meet or exceed the security
strength associated with the bit length of n", [NIST FIPS 186-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf))

Regarding cSHAKE (you probably meant SHAKE; cSHAKE is its customizable variant that is used to define KMAC and TupleHash), you could use any output equal to or larger than 512 bits. The [NIST FIPS 186-5 draft](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-5-draft.pdf) mandates SHAKE256 with 512-bit output.